# How can delete the old 10gb of documents if all indices reachs 100 gb?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Vm which has 138G of space, i deployed in elasticsearch, i defined ILM which looks like :

[image]

[image]

[image]

If all indices reachs the 100GB, then i would like to delete the old 10GB of documents,  How can i modify this ILM to do that ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ILM does not have a mechanism to delete based on conditions within the cluster state, i.e. that the sum(bytes) of all indices is greater than 100GB.

All movement between ILM phases is done via [timing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_timing.html). So if you want to do "pure" ILM to manage deletions, you'll need to somewhat guess as to how long it typically takes to get to 100GB total volume and set the delete `min_age` to be that.

Alternatively, you can have a little cronjob that checks the `_cluster/stats` for the current storage size and deletes the older indices as needed.

Comment: mike, if i want "pure" ILM, in that case :  is it possible to update the ILM that i difined by adding the delete phase, or i should delete the whole ILM and redefine it from scratch ?

Comment: yes, you can update an ILM policy and add in the delete phase, but be aware that it'll go and retroactively apply that policy,  so any existing data that matches the delete criteria (older than x days) will be deleted.